# jQuery Query String Object

Tags: jquery, variables, parameters, set

According to the documentation located here: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

In order to customize `$.query`'s parameters you need to: (quote)

> There are now some customizations which can be done, mostly dealing
>   with parsing and with toString generation. **The options are set by**
>    **creating jQuery.query as an object** of settings ***before including the***
>    ***jQuery.query source code*** on your page as seen below:

So I am trying the example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery.query = { numbers: false, hash: true };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.query.js"></script>
```

And this is what I get:

```
missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]   

var jQuery.query = { numbers: false, hash: true };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define a variable like that. Don't use `var` to add properties to an already existing variable or object.

Use this

```
jQuery.query = { numbers: false, hash: true };
```

Comment: +1, thanks Shankar for explaining this to me, it's the solution. In order not to open a new question related to same plugin I edited this one, do you mind checking the edit please?

Comment: There is no harm if `+` gets converted to `%2B` in the url. When you read it on the server side it will be `+` only.

Comment: I know is no harm, but it affects my view page.

Comment: Try to set `space: false` in the `jQuery.query` object.

Comment: I have tried that it won't work... I have created a question related to this `bug` (i think) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180357/query-string-plugin-converts-to-2b