# Query String plugin converts + to %2B

Tags: jquery, query-string

Using this jquery plugin: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

So I have this url: `results?search_query=alex+voievod` and I need to add `&page=2`, which I do it with the mentioned plugin.

Now the problem is that it converts `+` to `%2B` and it and it affects my **view page**. I have tried setting `spaces: false` as it says in the documentation (even though is `spaces: VALUE` not `space`)

But it won't work, it adds the parameter but it also changes + as mentioned above:

`results?search_query=alex%2Bvoievod&page=2`

What am I missing?

> space
>
> The default value for this is true as most people prefer plus signs in query strings to be converted to spaces. It's standard
>   practice to use plus signs to represent spaces in query strings to
>   avoid the dreaded %20 so the parser has been updated and, by default,
>   converts plus signs to spaces. However, this feature can be disabled
>   if you decide you need literal plus signs in your query strings.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $.query = { spaces: false }; </script>
<script src="<?=base_url();?>resources/js/libs/jquery.query.js"></script>
```

Inside jquery.query.js:

```
new function(settings) { 
  // Various Settings
  var $separator = settings.separator || '&';
  var $spaces = settings.spaces === false ? false : true;
  alert($spaces);->Returns the value as set, true or false.
  var $suffix = settings.suffix === false ? '' : '[]';
```

I have read a bit the code, but I can't find where is the bug having in mind that `spaces` has no effect.

Edit:
The code I use with `$.query`

```
var cur_page = $.query.get('page');
if (cur_page.length == 0){var next_page = cur_page + 2;}
else { var next_page = cur_page + 1; }
var page = $.query.set('page', next_page).toString();
alert(page);
/*window.location.replace(page);*/
```

I am going to try and contact the creator of this plugin: https://github.com/blairmitchelmore/jquery.plugins/blob/master/jquery.query.js

Comment: Can yo show your code how you are using it? Are you using `toString` method to get the combined string?

Answer (score 0):

Look at its source code, I see you that if you have `+` in your query string then set `space` to `true` because it converts them to (space) and then using `toString()` converts back them to `+`. Try this.

```
$.query = { spaces: true };
$.query.toString();
```

Comment: I added the code I use with `$.query` in the edit. `.toString()` is used, I am still checking the source code to see where this may bug be caused because no mather if `true` or `false` is set to `spaces` the same result is being output.